# Many to Many model with a dropdown in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a Many to Many relation with a model in between, I have a Client model, and a Zone model, each client may have access to different zones, and each zone may have multiple clients.

Therefore I created a model called Access Permission, that stores said relation, and I want to show a dropdown selector in the post form that shows the existing clients and zones, or to ask for the Id of an existing object, instead of showing the form to create new ones.

These are my models:

```
class Zone(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)


class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    birthDate = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)


class AccessPermission(models.Model):
    idClient = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    idZone = models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

And these my current serializers:

```
class ZoneSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Zone
        fields = ('name',)


class ClientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    zones = ZonesSerializer(source='accesspermission_set', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('name', 'birthDate',  'zones')


class AccessPermissionSerializer(serializers.ManyRelatedField):
    idClient = ClientSerializer(many=False)
    idZone = ZoneSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = AccessPermission
        fields = ('idClient', 'idZone')
```

Is there any way to ask for the Id of an existing object, or show the existing ones, instead of the fields to create new ones?

Comment: OK. So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I edited and stated the question more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

> models

```
class AccessPermission(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

> serializers

```
class AccessPermissionSerializer(serializers.ManyRelatedField):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    client_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Client.objects.all(), source='client', allow_null=False, required=True
    )
    zone_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Zone.objects.all(), source='zone', allow_null=False, required=True
    )
    class Meta:
        model = AccessPermission
        fields = (
            'id', 'client_id', 'zone_id'
        )
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Yes! This is what I was looking for, thank you so much.